# Google Form onSubmit does not have response object

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I've been using a google script for a Google Form that was working and now is broken.

Here is the sample of the code:

```
var Logger = BetterLog.useSpreadsheet('spreadsheet-key-removed')

function onSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))
  var response
  var d
  if (typeof e.response !== 'undefined' && e.response.getItemResponses) {
    response = e.response.getItemResponses()
    // Do stuff
  } else {
    d = d + 'Error with response.'
  }
}
```

I've added logging and I would expect to see a response object but for some reason there is none.
This is all I get back for e 
{"authMode":{},"triggerUid":307615524}

Comment: The only thing that I use the Forms event object for is to get the response ID.  And then use the response ID to get the response.  I don't have any proof of this, but the Forms event object seems to have some history of not being as reliable as it "should" be.  I don't think that the `e` event object is a JSON (JavaScript) object.  It's a object, but not a JSON object.  So, logging it, is not a reliable way to know whether it has data in it or not.

Comment: Could you provide an example of this?

Comment: `var resID = e.response.getId(); var myForm = FormApp.getActiveForm(); var theResponse = myForm.getResponse(resID);`

Comment: Thanks Sandy. It turned out that I needed to re-authorize the script. For some reason it lost it. Now every thing is working. Your code helped it throw a Authorization is required to perform that action, and that led me to the solution. Run the function again and have it ask for auth.